# Differences between javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I know this question might be silly just would like to know, and I am not sure whether the topic matches to my current asking. But still  thought to ask it.

```
  <button id="Clk">Click on me</button>

   document.getElementById("Clk").onclick = function(){alert("firedme!")}

   document.getElementById("Clk").onclick = fire();

   function fire(){alert("I am fired!")}
```

I see the first one "function" is not triggered on page load or refresh but where as second one  fire() gets triggered
 when page loaded, and later this function doesn't get triggered on click. I am confused, just need clarifications in this.

Comment: You are not executing the first one, then why are you executing the second one with those `()`? Remove them and you're fine.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The second one fires immediately because you used parenthesis `()`. When assigning an event handler to an existing function, don't include the parenthesis.

What happens is the function executes straight away, and the return value is assigned as the event handler.

To illustrate, it is the same as doing:

```
var result = fire();
console.log( result ); // undefined

document.getElementById("Clk").onclick = result;
```

As you can see, `undefined` is passed as the event handler.

Answer (score 13):

You need to pass `fire` to `onclick` as a function reference, not an invocation.

```
 document.getElementById("Clk").onclick = fire;
```

When you pass `fire()` to the onclick handler, it triggers immediately and the return from the function is what you are setting onclick too. By passing a reference to the function, it stops it from running until the event is triggered. It's essentially the same as the anonymous function handler above.

rlemon was kind enough to make you a nice demonstration [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rlemon/fC8WN/) <-- here

Answer (score 3):

Also, I would like to add few more things.

First, think of `onclick` as an ordinary property of an object.

So, `object.onclick = value` where `value = functionName()` is 
perfectly alright, for example, `functionName()` could be returning a value 
using `return something;`

But `onclick` is not an ordinary property. When JS engine in browser 
encounters assignments to event based properties (e.g. `onclick`,`ondblclick`,`onmouseover`, etc.), it creates a stack for each
element, consisting of mapping b/w
*onSomeEvent* and *handler*.

The handler is a function object. But if you do something like
`element.onSomeEvent = functionName();` you are simply calling the 
function `functionName()` and this would have been alright if 
`functionName()` was defined as

```
function functionName() {return function(){/*do something*/};}
```

But because `functionName` in your case is not returning a function, you see an unexpected result. This is the major 
drawback of languages like JavaScript. In a strongly typed language that would have 
thrown an error... because

```
class Element {
    Function onclick = null;
    Function ondblclick = null;
    /*other code*/
}
document.getElementById('idName').onclick = new Function(); // correct
document.getElementById('idName').onclick = function(){}; // correct
document.getElementById('idName').onclick = functionName();
/*
 * correct if functionName defined as 
 * Function functionName() {return new Function();} or
 * Function functionName() {return function(){};}
 * and incorrect for any other case
 */
```

Comment: It should be noted the second (or N assignments) over write previous listeners (as you described about it being a property). Using .addEventListener allows you to stack multiple listeners to an element.